# Can social sciences have a non-subject -related axiomatic foundation? Why not?

Tags: axiom, philosophy-of-social-sciences

Can social sciences have a non-subject -related axiomatic foundation? Why not?

Problems:

Interpretation is always relative to **subjective interpretation**. Which is not similar in natural sciences. In natural sciences it's possible to attain an **observation** that's **the same for different subjects** (or, at least, even if it's not physically the same, due to differences in senses, it's *consistently demonstrateable* and/or *agreeable* as such). In soc. sci. it can be speculated that there will be more bias depending on the orientation of the observer. Thus observers necessarily cannot observe the same thing.

Comment: It seems to me that Islamic society (at its best) has a non-subject related axiomatic foundation. The idea is that society should be organised so as to be amenable to a life of surrender of the ego, the axiom being that all is Al-Lah (the One),or an axiom of Unity. Not sure if this would qualify but maybe. . .  . .

Comment: That we can not have the same degree of consensus on social observations that we have on physical, or even biological, ones is presumably explained by the complexity and vagueness of the basic vocabulary involved. As it increases from physics to chemistry to biology to anthropology to psychology to sociology, the degree of consensus decreases.

Comment: Personally i see no reason why social science cannot be like any other science. In fact I believe it is. But a truly scientific study of society would be incredibly contentious. What for example, if it showed that religion was damaging. Or that capitalism was damaging. What if it upset the status quo? I believe people are studying this, but.the public probably aren't getting the memo's. It sounds tin foil hat, but only if you have never tried to really imagine a better world, and have never read Orwell.

Comment: @Richard Yeah, but that would suggest that it should be classified perhaps further than "science" (which is too broad). The problem that this question posits is related to mixing of "foundations of science" (because all sciences use the concept 'science'). Thus e.g. "economic science" can be perceived to "claim legitimacy" based on "physical science", even if their methodologies and verificationism would be grossly different. Thus I'm not sure if they all "deserve to be called science". Or whether it could be reasonable to call them "soft sciences". How about "social semi-science"?

Comment: I personally think that "economic science" is definitely a misapplication of the concept of "science". It does not fulfill enough of scientific method IMO. Thus I would prefer to call it "economic semi-science". https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/semiscientific I wonder if other people would agree with this and start to use the term "semiscience" for "partially scientific study fields that are weaker than physical sciences".

Comment: @PeterJ That's a good point, but so does mathematics and physics. At least in some sense (not fully non-subjective, but does have some form of non-subjectivity/objectivity).

Comment: @mavavilj There is a tendancy for some firmly humanities subjects to call themselves sciences I agree. I don't know why they.do that. But the basic methods of science can be applied to anything which can be repeated. The problems associated with experimenting on people make the ethics difficult. But societies in microcosm and control groups could be created etc. who wants to live in the tyranny group though? This is why social sciences rely heavily on examples from history.

Comment: @Richard Which though could be still relative to subjective values. I.e. nazism is good from nazi perspective, bad from someone else's.

Comment: @mavavilj  science is not subjective (in the common meaning of the word).
It depends on what the study is. Is it, which social structure is best for a one government world? Which is best for any nation surrounded by communist states? Which is the most long term stable, which is the ....
The experiments must be set up to remove subjectivity.
I would suggest a good study would be, which social and political structure is best for long term stability (that is, long term peace).

Comment: @Richard Yes, but that's a  subjective goal/preference. Why not study, what arrangements produce most benefit for the strongest members? And then implement some sort of slave system? It's just a matter of preference tbh, which is why I don't think it can be "scientific". Because merely by changing preferences, the theory of "other preferences" collapses. A soc. sci. theory is true, only if it "appeals" to the subject. Whereas physical theory is true, because it "appears the same" to the subject.

Comment: Science is a control system. Imagine your new shower has no temperature markings. You twist the knob subjectively one way or another until the temperature is correct. Your objective was a shower with a temperature of about 40-50 degrees, but your actions to achieve that were chaotic. In this case your objective would be what? A society which is 'fair'? A society which produces most work output? What knobs are you going to chaotically twiddle to achieve this?

Comment: @Richard But I think that those are subjective. I.e. fair is subjective, most work is subjective.

Comment: @mavavilj so are you suggesting that it is not possible to think of an objective result to any social experiment?
What about: Find the best social structure for maximising the average life expectancy of it's citizens?
That gives us an absolutely non-subjective positive integer measurement. I think it is possible to think of objective measurements for social experiements, and therefore, it is possible to subject society to science.

Comment: @Richard Only if every interpreter would agree with the definition and interpretation of e.g. "fair". And I think that it's impossible, because "fairness" is a complicated concept, and not consistent. Thus I also suggest, not relying on concepts such as that, because they are too ambigious. I can have my "fair" and you can have your "fair", but thinking that we can have a common and consistent fair is possibly waste of time. Thus we may not need to speculate about "communal fairness" or "utilitarian fairness", because they are too ambigious and unattainable.

Comment: Also, scientifically, to measure the outcome of something claimed to produce "fairness". The only entirely accurate measurement would be to ask confirmation from every subject subjected to said policies and ask "do you agree that this is 'fair'?". One exception and it would not be exactly accurate anymore, or i.e. that "fairness" is not an exact phenomenon. Would it then make sense to claim that "this is fair", if some subpopulation says "this is exploitation"?